# Installing Hera parallel to Win 10

Tags: system-installation, release-hera

Afaik, this exact issue is not answered here and I am too much of a noob to really follow this one: [Installing elementary OS alongside Windows 10](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/installing-elementary-os-alongside-windows-10)

So to my problem:

When it comes to choose the type of installation it says that I have installed Win 10 and how do I want to proceed.

But it DOES NOT give me the option to install it alongside Win 10.

The first option I have is to erase all and to install elementary.

Then I can enable the two tick boxes below (Encrypt and use LVM)

Then there comes the separation line and under that I can choose something different.

In all tutorial videos that i could find there is always a first option that says something like: " Install alongside existing OS".

I use an Acer TravelMate 5720 and Win 10 Pro 32 Bit. It´s fully registered.

Thank you all very much in advance for your ideas!

Comment: If your Windows is installed as UEFI, do you have Secure Boot/UEFI enabled when booting Elementary? If you boot the flash drive/DVD with Elementary as a Legacy Boot, you won't be able to install it alongside Windows.

Comment: Hey Hasan, thank you very much for your answer! This is a bit of a bummer as I think my machine is too old to support that. At least I did not see any of those options in the BIOS. I am thinking about creating a partition manually now but what puzzles me is that the Win Explorer (in Windows) says the Win partition is 0,93 GB big, while the Elementary installation says its only 607 MB with 385  MB in use... Which one should I beleave? Thanks to all the nice people around here!

Comment: Do you only have one drive? Or is it possible that you have multiple drives and elementary doesn't detect one of them – the one where Windows itself is installed? Windows 10 makes multiple partitions, some of them are only megabytes in size, but the main partition is always large – it's definitely bigger than 1 GB. Try looking for a partition that is at least 40GB big…

Answer (score 0):

Ir you have only one drive with Windows 10, you have to resize it and leave for example 50 GB of unallocated space for Elementary. Then during the Elementary OS installation you will be able to use unallocated space to create partitions there.